# Query one set of data vs another when a condition exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, where-clause, window-functions

I am looking for a better SQL solution for my requirement:
I have data of this nature

```
qty  id  sub-id  counter
100  id1  id1      0
200  id2  id2      0
150  id2  id2-1    1
50   id2  id2-2    2
120  id3  id3      0
140  id4  id4      0
80   id4  id4-1    1
60   id4  id4-2    2
```

The data contains master data when the counter = 0. In some cases, there is derived or sub-data, it is identified by counter > 0. The qty column of sub-data adds up to match the master data.

Need to write a query that fetches the data with counter = 0 when there are no records existing for the same id with counter > 0 else fetch the records with counter > 0

I am able to write it as 2 separate queries and using a UNION - is it possible to simplify the query and avoid a UNION statement?

Comment: Show us your union query.

Comment: "I am able to write it as 2 separate queries".  Where???  We don't see a single query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, sum(counter) over(partition by id) sum_counter
    from mytable t
) t
where sum_counter = O or counter > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for answering - looks like this might work - will give it a try

Comment: @Sajid: this query gives you the result that you want, no need to combine it with something else. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Could work with LEAD as well

```
;with lead_cte as (
    select *, lead([counter]) over (partition by id order by qty desc) lead_counter
    from some_table)
select * from lead_cte where lead_counter=0 or [counter]>0;
```